# The model item passed does not match the expected IEnumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework

I am building a project for school. I am almost there but there is one error I can't fix.
I am making a bike reservation asp.net website.
The error says I pass a list to the index page of reservations and it expects an IEnumerable.
I already tried making the expected a list, but that also gives an error.

I have seen other fixes of this problem, but I can't get it to work.

Here is my original index method.

```
    // GET: Reservations
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var reservations = db.Reservations.Include(r => r.Bike).Include(r => r.Customer).Include(r => r.DropoffStore).Include(r => r.PickupStore);
        return View(reservations.ToList());
    }
```

Here is my new Controller index method that i got from someone else, but i dont know why i wont work:

```
    // GET: Reservations
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var reservations = db.Reservations.Include(r => r.Bike).Include(r => r.Customer).Include(r => r.DropoffStore).Include(r => r.PickupStore);

        IEnumerable<ReservationViewModel> reservationViewModels = new List<ReservationViewModel>();

        foreach (var reservation in reservations)
        {
            var reservationViewModel = new ReservationViewModel
            {

            };

            reservationViewModels.ToList().Add(reservationViewModel);

        }

        return View(reservationViewModels);
    }
```

Here is my index page:

```
@model IEnumerable<ASP.NET_Framwork_for_real_bitch.ViewModels.ReservationViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Reservation.Customer.FirstName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Reservation.Customer.LastName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Reservation.Customer.Email)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Reservation.Customer.Gender)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Reservation.DropoffStore_Id)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Reservation.PickupStore_Id)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Reservation.StartDate)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Reservation.EndDate)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Reservation.Customer.FirstName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Reservation.Customer.LastName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Reservation.Customer.Email)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Reservation.Customer.Gender)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Reservation.DropoffStore.StoreName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Reservation.PickupStore.StoreName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Reservation.StartDate)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Reservation.EndDate)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Reservation.Id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Reservation.Id })
    </td>
</tr>
}

</table>
```

This is the exact error:

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ASP.NET_Framwork_for_real_bitch.Models.Reservation]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[ASP.NET_Framwork_for_real_bitch.ViewModels.ReservationViewModel]'.
```

my Whole ReservationViewModel:

```
using ASP.NET_Framwork_for_real_bitch.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace ASP.NET_Framwork_for_real_bitch.ViewModels
{
    public class ReservationViewModel
    {
        private BikeShoppaModel db = new BikeShoppaModel();
        public Reservation Reservation { get; set; }
        public SelectList DropoffStore_Id { get; private set; }
        public SelectList PickupStore_Id { get; private set; }
        public SelectList Bikes { get; private set; }
        public SelectList CustomerGender { get; set; }
        public int TotalDays { get; set; }
        public double TotalPrice { get; set; }
        public ReservationViewModel()
        {
            DropoffStore_Id = new SelectList(db.Stores, "Id", "StoreName");
            PickupStore_Id = new SelectList(db.Stores, "Id", "StoreName");
            Bikes = new SelectList(db.Bikes, "Id", "Brand");
            CustomerGender = new SelectList(db.Customers, "Id", "Gender");
        }
        public ReservationViewModel(int id) : this()
        {
            Reservation = db.Reservations.Find(id);
            TotalDays = (Reservation.EndDate.Date - Reservation.StartDate.Date).Days + 1;
        }

        public void Save()
        {
            if(Reservation.Id > 0)
            {
                db.Entry(Reservation).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }
            else
            {
                db.Reservations.Add(Reservation);
            }



            db.SaveChanges();
        }   
    }
}
```

my Reservations model:

```
public class Reservation
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Customer")]
        [Display(Name = "Customer")]
        public int Customer_Id { get; set; }
        public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Bike")]
        public int Bike_Id { get; set; }
        public Bike Bike { get; set; }


        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [Column(TypeName = "Date")]
        [Display(Name = "Start date")]
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [Column(TypeName = "Date")]
        [Display(Name = "End date")]
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("PickupStore")]
        [Display(Name = "Pickup store")]
        public int PickupStore_Id { get; set; }
        public Store PickupStore { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("DropoffStore")]
        [Display(Name = "Dropoff store")]
        public int DropoffStore_Id { get; set; }
        public Store DropoffStore { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: you need to convert ``Reservation`` in Models to ``ReservationViewModel`` in ViewModels.You can use Automapper or extension method to do this

Comment: Can you clarify that? I am quite new to asp.net.

Comment: in the ``Index`` Action you send to the View collection of ``Reservation`` entity, but in the view you reference a collection ``ReservationViewModel``. so two object are not same.  you have 2 solutions : 1 - convert collection of ``Reservation`` to collection of ``ReservationViewModel`` in the Action and send it to view. 2 - use directly ``Reservation`` entity in the view. i recommend the first.

Comment: It has proven to be a good style on Stackoverflow (and elsewhere, but this leads too far here) to respond to comments and help.

Answer (score 0):

You return a list of reservations in your Controller index method. Your View expects an IEnumerable of ReservationViewModels. So your Controller produces apples but your view needs oranges. 
So you have to convert apples to oranges to make that work - one of the several advantages being a software developer to get that done :-)
Try something like this:

```
var reservations = db.Reservations.Include(r => r.Bike).Include(r => r.Customer).Include(r => r.DropoffStore).Include(r => r.PickupStore);

IEnumerable<ReservationViewModel> reservationViewModels = new List<ReservationViewModel>();

foreach (var reservation in reservations) 
{
    var reservationViewModel = new ReservationViewModel 
    {
        OneProperty = reservation.AnotherProperty
        //... other properties you need to convert ...
    }

    reservationViewModels.Add(reservationViewModel);
}

return View(reservationViewModels);
```

So you have to iterate over your apples (objects of type Reservation) and produce an orange (object of type ReservationViewModel) for each apple. At the end you pass that set of oranges (IEnuerable of ReservationViewModel= to your view and your done.

Comment: reservationViewModels.Add(reservationViewModel); gives an error, it does not contain a definition of add.

Comment: As properties do I need to add every property from my model?

Comment: Check typos, a List has an Add method (did you type that in lowercase?).

Comment: Only those properties, that you want to use in your View. Others would keep their default values (like 0 for an int or null for a string).

Answer (score 0):

Please replace Controller Index action method with below and post your comments:

```
// GET: Reservations
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var reservations = db.Reservations.Include(r => r.Bike).Include(r => r.Customer).Include(r => r.DropoffStore).Include(r => r.PickupStore);

    var reservationViewModels = new List<ReservationViewModel>();

    foreach (var reservation in reservations)
    {
        var reservationViewModel = new ReservationViewModel
        {

        };

        reservationViewModels.Add(reservationViewModel);
    }
    /* 
      // In short you can populate your viewmodels and return as below:
      return (reservations.Select(r => new ReservationViewModel{
      }).AsEnumerable());
    */

    return View(reservationViewModels.AsEnumerable());
}
```

Just a side note: You basically mixed up entity model and view model. It needs lot of cleaning and/or refactoring.